# win32gui shows some windows, that are not open

Tags: python, winapi, pywin32

I'm using the win32gui package for the first time. I found the following examples to printout all opened windows.

But I am wondering about that the log_app_list() function contains windows, that are not opened. For example 'Microsoft Store' and 'Einstellungen' (means settings in german). Can someone explain me this unexpected behavior?

```
import win32gui

def window_enum_handler(hwnd, resultList):
    if win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd) and win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd) != '':
        resultList.append((hwnd, win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)))

def get_app_list(handles=[]):
    mlst=[]
    win32gui.EnumWindows(window_enum_handler, handles)
    for handle in handles:
        mlst.append(handle)
    return mlst

def log_app_list():
    appwindows = get_app_list()
    for i in appwindows:
        print(i)

log_app_list()
```

Comment: It depends on the state of the process in the background, these windows are not "unopened", but the process is in the suspended state, you can check in the task manager, and The process "WinStore.App.exe" and "SystemSettings.exe" is in `Suspended` status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the state of the process in the background, these windows are not "unopened", but the process is in the `suspended` state, you can check in the task manager, and The process "WinStore.App.exe" and "SystemSettings.exe" is in Suspended status:
[image]

You could use [`DwmGetWindowAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwmapi/nf-dwmapi-dwmgetwindowattribute) with `DWMWA_CLOAKED` to get its cloaked property, to exclude them:

```
import win32gui
import ctypes
from ctypes import c_int
import ctypes.wintypes
from ctypes.wintypes import HWND, DWORD
dwmapi = ctypes.WinDLL("dwmapi")
DWMWA_CLOAKED = 14 
isCloacked = c_int(0)
def window_enum_handler(hwnd, resultList):
    if win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd) and win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd) != '':
        dwmapi.DwmGetWindowAttribute(HWND(hwnd), DWORD(DWMWA_CLOAKED), ctypes.byref(isCloacked), ctypes.sizeof(isCloacked))
        if(isCloacked.value == 0):
            resultList.append((hwnd, win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)))

def get_app_list(handles=[]):
    mlst=[]
    win32gui.EnumWindows(window_enum_handler, handles)
    for handle in handles:
        mlst.append(handle)
    return mlst

def log_app_list():
    appwindows = get_app_list()
    for i in appwindows:
        print(i)

log_app_list()
```

Comment: Hi @RicardoRose, does it solve your issue? Please feel free to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it and let me know if you have any questions.